# ETag not updated in PATCH response

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm testing my application that uses Drive API v2, and I noticed that I'm not
getting a new ETag in the response of a PATCH request.

I made some tests using the Google APIs Explorer. This is the PATCH request:

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B-TenPiSMBplMTJnVlYxTEEwQ28?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer ...
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
  "title": "file.tmp"
}
```

And this is the beginning of the PATCH response that shows the ETag `"EBHN0a_u6Vh64YcTBDNdNyfF7Hs/MTM4MTI2MTIxODY0MQ"`:

```
200 OK

Cache-Control:  no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding:  gzip
Content-Length:  1019
Content-Type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date:  Tue, 08 Oct 2013 19:46:36 GMT
Etag:  "EBHN0a_u6Vh64YcTBDNdNyfF7Hs/MTM4MTI2MTIxODY0MQ"
Expires:  Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma:  no-cache
Server:  GSE

{
  "kind": "drive#file",
  "id": "0B-TenPiSMBplMTJnVlYxTEEwQ28",
  "etag": "\"EBHN0a_u6Vh64YcTBDNdNyfF7Hs/MTM4MTI2MTIxODY0MQ\"",
  "selfLink": "https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B-TenPiSMBplMTJnVlYxTEEwQ28",
  "webContentLink": "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B-TenPiSMBplMTJnVlYxTEEwQ28&export=download",
  "alternateLink": "https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-TenPiSMBplMTJnVlYxTEEwQ28/edit?usp=drivesdk",
  "iconLink": "https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_10_generic_list.png",
  "title": "file.tmp",
```

But if I do a GET request just after the PATCH:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B-TenPiSMBplMTJnVlYxTEEwQ28?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Authorization:  Bearer ...
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer
```

In the response, I get an updated ETag (`"EBHN0a_u6Vh64YcTBDNdNyfF7Hs/MTM4MTI2MTU5NjAyNg"`):

```
200 OK

Cache-Control:  private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
Content-Encoding:  gzip
Content-Length:  1021
Content-Type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date:  Tue, 08 Oct 2013 19:48:44 GMT
Etag:  "EBHN0a_u6Vh64YcTBDNdNyfF7Hs/MTM4MTI2MTU5NjAyNg"
Expires:  Tue, 08 Oct 2013 19:48:44 GMT
Server:  GSE

{
  "kind": "drive#file",
  "id": "0B-TenPiSMBplMTJnVlYxTEEwQ28",
  "etag": "\"EBHN0a_u6Vh64YcTBDNdNyfF7Hs/MTM4MTI2MTU5NjAyNg\"",
  "selfLink": "https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B-TenPiSMBplMTJnVlYxTEEwQ28",
  "webContentLink": "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B-TenPiSMBplMTJnVlYxTEEwQ28&export=download",
  "alternateLink": "https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-TenPiSMBplMTJnVlYxTEEwQ28/edit?usp=drivesdk",
  "iconLink": "https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_10_generic_list.png",
  "title": "file.tmp",
```

Is this the intended behavior? I was expecting to get the updated ETag in the
PATCH response to avoid another roundtrip to the server. Notice also that I
experienced the same behavior using PUT instead of PATCH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, Drive is somewhat asynchronous under the hood. Stuff like etags and some URLs are populated asynchronously after your PATCH has completed.